# Solving $4^{x-1}+\frac14\left(7^x+8^x+9^x\right)=2016^{x/4}$

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function

> Solve for $x$: $$4^{x-1}+\frac{7^x+8^x+9^x}{4}=2016^{x/4}$$

My work: $$\frac{4^x+7^x+8^x+9^x}{4}=(4*7*8*9)^{x/4}$$
I can take the log of both sides then move the $x/4$ to the front of the log on the right, but that's not getting me anywhere.

Comment: $x=0$ works.  Beyond that...

Comment: Yeah I can see x=0 works, but I thought I could get there algebraically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By the [AM-GM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means) inequality, the arithmetic mean of $4^x, 7^x, 8^x, 9^x$, is greater than or equal to the geometric mean of same.  More importantly, equality holds only if $4^x=7^x=8^x=9^x$.  This holds exactly when $x=0$, and for no other $x$.

Comment: Doesn't it state that the arithmetic mean is "greater than or equal" to the geometric mean?